# When is the best time to create a PayPal Webhook?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I am using the PayPal API to create a Webhook, and not the Developer site. When is the best time to do this? Do I create the webhook before the payment is created, after the payment is created, or after the payment is executed? According to the API documentation, the webhook needs to be created only once in the lifetime of the app. What happens if a new webhook is created each time the app is used?
What I have:

1. processPayment: the payment details are defined, the payment is created, the user is redirected to PayPal.
2. executePayment: the user is returned from PayPal, the payment is executed.

On notify:

1. verifyPayment: calls a function to validate Webhook signature.
2. Post-processing in the Site's database.

P.S. Where/how is the webhook Id generated?

Comment: What is your goal for the webhook?

Comment: To receive and process notification events from PayPal. When the payment has actually been completed, or voided, receive the notification, validate the notification, and update the site's database accordingly. To do everything PDT/IPN does.

Answer (score 0):

Webhook needs to be created before making a payment transaction if you want to get notified of the payment. If there are multiple Webhooks configured on your app and if you have same set of events subscribed on both, you would receive notifications on both Webhooks.

Thanks!